# Como é calculado o grau de autoridade de um site?

Tags: seo

Alguém pode me explicar melhor como é medido o grau de autoridade de um site? Hoje no [http://www.meets.com.br](https://meets.com.br) Temos um grau de autoridade 28 segundo o [Ubersuggest](https://app.neilpatel.com/br/traffic_analyzer/overview?lang=pt&locId=2076&domain=meets.com.br). Em outros sites temos um grau menor e outros maior. Qual a referência e se isso impacta diretamente nas buscas do Google?

Comment: Por curiosidade e fiz a análise do `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/` e  o atribuiu grau de autoridade 94.

Comment: Rapaz mas o que vc está querendo saber é quais os critérios o Google usa para colocar um site na primeira posição... Esse é o segredo guardado a 7 chaves, e que de tempos em tempos eles mudam o algoritmo de rankeamento https://prnt.sc/qv44o9 resumindo, ninguém vai conseguir te responder com  certeza, e mesmo se responder, não deve durar mais  de 3 meses até eles atualizaram o algoritmo. O que vc deve fazer e seguir as boas práticas de SEO padrão, além de manter seu site acessível, com boa performance, seguro, e sem  black hats. Além do mais essa não parece uma ferramenta oficial da Google

Comment: Uma dica a mais, parece que um dos fatores fortes de autorida são os Back Links, então se houver um link para o seu site na Wikipedia ou na Endeavour ou na Exame, o seu site vai ganhando uns pontos de Autoridade, pois outros sites de confiança estão apontando para o seu. Mas isso é só uma peça de um quebra cabeças gigantesco e que muda com o tempo. (lembre-se quantidade não é qualidade, um site do black list do google que aponte paro o seu vai é te fazer perder pontos, *talvez*)